# Need to Replace Regex expression with space

Tags: java, regex, string

I have following regex words `/ \ * ? [ ]` . if any word is found in the string then it should be replaced with **blank Space**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must have tried something?

Comment: i tried it but replacing the every character at a time.

Comment: Then complete your question by adding your attempt

Comment: i have done same as described by #aGer user.

Comment: "*i have done same as described by #aGer user*" then put it in your question. Not many people are going to read your comments before they will decide to post answer similar to aGer's one, which you probably want to avoid since as you claim you tried it already.

Comment: Also `replace` doesn't use regex. Try with `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the whole inside a regex character class. And use four backslashes to match a single literal backslash character.

```
string.replaceAll("[/\\\\*?\\[\\]]", " ");
```